# Как поставить русский интрефейс QT5.2 Xubuntu 13.10?

Tags: qt4, xubuntu

Здравствуйте!

Как поставить русский интерфейс QT Creator 5.2 Xubuntu 13.10? Файлы с русской локалью вроде есть. Ответ ниже не помог. Спасибо.

Установил через магазин приложений Xubuntu.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Ну а если из консоли попробовать ?

`LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8 qtcreator`

Если конечно у вас установлена локаль  ru_RU.UTF-8.

Comment: @pyatak, не сработало. Хотя файл есть. В настройках видит только английский. Если выставить системный язык, то всё равно английский язык.

Comment: А как локаль  ru_RU.UTF-8 установить?